# Can you install Ros2 humble in raspian?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ros2

I am currently working on a project with ros2 humble that must be run on a raspberryPi, and i am currently in need of using a docker, since i could not find a way of installing ros2  humble native in a raspianOS, my  question is, can you instal directly in raspian or do I need to make a new boot for a ubuntu server version in order to run it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install `humble` from [source code](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html), otherwise, install docker and try to run the  `docker pull` command getting an [`arm`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/ros/) architecture if necessary or the standard [`amd`](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros/tags) one.